# $(p∧q)↔(p∨q) = p↔q$ prove using logical statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I am stuck on this question right now and it'd be great if someone can help me out.
I managed to start it like this and it just stops there...
$(p\land q)\leftrightarrow (p \lor q) \iff(p\land q)\rightarrow (p\lor q) \land (p\lor q)\rightarrow (p\land q)$

Answer (score 0):

For theses types of proofs you want to prove the left hand side is the right hand side. I don't know what side you're starting with, but this is my solution. I am going to start with the left hand side of this equation: $(p \land q) \leftrightarrow (p \lor q)$.

$$
1.\space ((p \land q) \rightarrow (p \lor q))\land ((p \lor q)\rightarrow (p \land q)) \qquad \text{Def.} p\leftrightarrow q \equiv (p\rightarrow q) \land (q\rightarrow p)
\\
2. \space (\lnot(p\land q) \lor (p \lor q)) \land (\lnot(p\lor q) \lor (p\land q)) \qquad \text{Def.}p\rightarrow q \equiv \lnot p\lor q
\\
3. \space ((\lnot p \lor \lnot q)\lor (p \lor q)) \land((\lnot p \land \lnot q)\lor (p \land q)) \qquad \text{DeMorgan's} \\ 
4. ((\lnot p \lor p)\lor (\lnot q\lor q))\land ((\lnot p\land \lnot q) \lor (p\land q)) \qquad \text{Associative Property} \\ 
5.\space  (T\lor T) \land ((\lnot p\land \lnot q) \lor (p\land q)) \equiv (\lnot p\land \lnot q) \lor (p\land q) \qquad \text{Identity and Domination Laws} \\
6.\space (\lnot p\land \lnot q) \lor (p\land q) \equiv p \leftrightarrow q \qquad \text{Def.} p \leftrightarrow q \equiv (p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \\ \\ \boxed{}$$

Any questions on this let me know. I used Rosen's definition for logical equivalences for my justifications.

Answer (score 0):

1. $(p\land q)\iff (p\lor q)$
2. $[(p\land q)\implies (p\lor q)]\land [(p\lor q)\implies (p\land q)]$
3. $[\neg(p\land q)\lor (p\lor q)]\land [\neg(p\lor q)\lor (p\land q)]$
4. $\underbrace{(\neg p\lor\neg q \lor p\lor q)}_{\text{True}}\land [(\neg p\land \neg q)\lor (p\land q)]$
5. $(\neg p\land \neg q)\lor (p\land q)$
6. $\underbrace{(\neg p\lor p)}_{\text{True}}\land (\neg p\lor q)\land (\neg q\lor p)\land \underbrace{(\neg q\lor q)}_{\text{True}}$
7. $(\neg p\lor q)\land (\neg q\lor p)$
8. $(p\implies q)\land (q\implies p)$
9. $q\iff p$

Where all lines are equivalent $\square$.

Comment: what rule did you apply for 6th line?

Comment: @Fei Distributive property https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally the equivalence $(p \lor q) \to (p \land q) \iff p \leftrightarrow q$ already holds.

**Proof:** $(\Longleftarrow)$ If $p \leftrightarrow q$ then we get
$$ 
(p \lor q) \to (p \land q) \iff
(p \lor p) \to (p \land p) \iff
p \to p \iff \text{True}
$$
$(\Longrightarrow)$ Assuming $H: (p \lor q) \to (p \land q)$ try to show $p \to q$. For this, assume $p$, then we can conclude $p \lor q$ and therefore $p \land q$ by $H$, finally giving us $q$. In the same fashion we can show $q \to p$ and therefore overall $p \leftrightarrow q$.

Answer (score 0):

$1. (p\land q)\leftrightarrow (p\lor q)$

$2. [(p\land q)\to (p\lor q)]\land[(p\lor q)\to (p\land q)]$

$3. (p\lor q)\to (p\land q)$

$4. (p\to q)\land (q\to p)$

$5.  p\leftrightarrow q$

**Note**. All numbered propositions are equivalent. Also $(2)$ equivalent to $(3)$, because $(p\land q)\to (p\lor q)$ is a tautology.